# Python append is appending the wrong data

Tags: python, append

I have a Python program that gets and retrieves info for nba basketball games. In my example there are 6 games being played, I get all my info for the games and put it into the variable gameInfo.  gameInfo is correct, when I print it it comes out fine, each game is correct. But when I finalPush["games"].append(gameInfo) it adds the most recent gameInfo i amount of times, so the final output of finalPush["games"] is the last game appended 6 times.  I want the information of all 6 games into finalPush["games"]. Any help would be appreciated, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
def add_game_info_to_json():
finalPush = {"games": []}
gameInfo = {
    "teamHome": "",
    "teamAway": "",
    "recordHome": "",
    "recordAway": "",
    "colorHome": "",
    "colorAway": "",
    "line": "",
    "overunder": "",
    "homeTextColor": "",
    "awayTextColor": "",
    "homeIndex": "",
    "awayIndex": "",
    "time": ""
}

with open('teamMaster.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

i = 0
z = 0

while i < (len(teams_list)/2):
    gameInfo.update(time = game_status_list[i])
    gameInfo.update(teamAway = teams_list[i+z])
    gameInfo.update(recordAway = records_list[i + z])
    gameInfo.update(line = betting_list[i + z])
    for team in data:
        if team == gameInfo["teamAway"]:
            gameInfo.update(colorAway = data[team]["color"])
            gameInfo.update(awayTextColor = data[team]["textColor"])
            gameInfo.update(awayIndex = data[team]["index"])

    z += 1
    gameInfo.update(teamHome = teams_list[i+z])
    gameInfo.update(recordHome = records_list[i + z])
    gameInfo.update(overunder = betting_list[i + z])
    for team in data:
        if team == gameInfo["teamHome"]:
            gameInfo.update(colorHome = data[team]["color"])
            gameInfo.update(homeTextColor = data[team]["textColor"])
            gameInfo.update(homeIndex = data[team]["index"])
    print(gameInfo)
    i += 1
    finalPush["games"].append(gameInfo)
    print(finalPush)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You append 6 times the same dict, which you continue to update.

You must append a copy of your dict:

```
finalPush["games"].append(gameInfo.copy())
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so much.  That's exactly what it was, I was losing my mind trying to figure it out